# Кроссдоменное отправка запроса с Angular

Tags: angularjs, http, cross-domain

Может кто нибудь посоветовать мне раширение для *Chrome* или сказать какие 
 настройки нужны чтоб отправить **HTTP** запрос с локалхоста на сервер.

---

Доступы на сервер есть.

Comment: Вам нужна штука под названием CORS, де-факто - заголовок `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` на сервере.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел раширение для Chrome, вот и [он](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog).

как подсказал [Etki](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/16095/etki) в комментарии.

> Вам нужна штука под названием CORS, де-факто - заголовок Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * на сервере.

Answer (score -1):

Если PHP, то:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```